# I'm having trouble setting up a Remove from Library button which removes an object from a database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

Sorry if this is a bit scrambled. I've stayed up all night working on this. I've been trying to come up with a `Remove from Library` button in the Library App I've been working on, which basically just removes an object from a database but having some difficulty. Setting up the `Add to Library` button was pretty easy.

```
<button type="submit">Add to Library</button>
```

This button is connected to this POST route.

```
router.post("/book/:id", [
  body("title", "Title must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    const collection = new Collection({
      title: req.body.title,
      user: req.user.username,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      async.parallel((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.render("book", {
          title,
          user,
          createdAt,
          errors: errors.array(),
        });
      });
      return;
    }
    collection.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/users/profile");
    });
  },
]);
```

And it works just fine. I have some fake data set up and when I click on a book and click the Add to Library button, it adds all the information to my `Collection` schema which is then stored in my mongo database. Everything is mapped out inside my `profile` page where you can view which books I've added.

```
const PopularBooks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Harry Potter",
    characters: [
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "Harry Potter",
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "Hermione",
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "Ron",
      },
    ],
}
```

The issue I've been having is I can click the Add to Library button as many times as I want and it keeps adding to my library, so multiple images of the same book was showing inside my user profile. I've been trying to remedy this by changing the Add to Library button to a Remove from Library button but I can't come up with the logic for checking if a certain book is in my `Collection` already and then changing the button logic from add to remove. I wrote this piece of code which I thought would work but it didn't help at all.

```
const searchCriteria = { id: req.params.id };
const inCollection = Collection.findOne(searchCriteria);

<% if (inCollection) { %>
<p>In Collection</p> // just a test
<% } %>
```

Then there's the logic for actually removing the object.

```
router.post(
  "/delete/:id",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    await Collection.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectID });
    return res.redirect("/");
  })
);
```

This code actually did work when I manually put in an ObjectID from a MongoDB and it deleted the object I wanted to but I couldn't figure out how to dynamically find an ObjectID using JavaScript. All help is appreciated.

Comment: @Aimsat thanks for the response. I did not. But I did completely redo the code which helped tremendously so I'm close.